# Save Session data in database

Tags: php, session, php-5.2

I have to save session data into database. I have written class for that. I tested class on php version 5.5.12/apache and it did work for me.

On production I have 5.2.9/iis and same class didn't work there.I get following error

> Fatal error: Interface 'SessionHandlerInterface' not found

Sample PHP Class

```
class SysSession implements SessionHandlerInterface
{

}
```

I have checked PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php) and interface is available for 5.2.9.

Comment: Your code is probably inside a namespace, which isn't supported in 5.2.

Comment: I am not using namespace. Also I tried use SessionHandlerInterface;

Comment: PHP docs say: `(PHP 5 >= 5.4.0, PHP 7)` for SessionHandlerInterface class.

Comment: Yes It means it should work for between 5 and 5.4.0 and 7. But in my case it worked on 5.5.12 and didn't work on 5.2.9. Strange

Comment: No, it means it works on version of 5 that are greater than or equal to 5.4.0.

Comment: Any work around for lower versions.

Comment: Don't bother. 5.2 was end-of-lifed over six years ago and lots of really significant changes have been introduced since. It will be an order of magnitude easier to just install a new (v7, hopefully) server than it will be to back-port 5.5 code to 5.2.